# drupal 8 item.url returns error on non default language

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Recently my drupal 8 site which is running in both english and french fails to load in french. (English is the default language)

The error returned is

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route "" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider->getRouteByName() (line 187 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteProvider.php).

I've tracked it down to the item.url function in menu.html.twig

> {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}

it returns the url is fine in english, and returns the correct item.title if called outside of link() in both languages, it's just "link.url" in the french version. Any ideas?